# Including a predictor that cannot be assessed in preverbal/non-verbal children

Tags: r, logistic, prediction, missing-data, regression-strategies

I'm building a prediction model (logistic regression, using R) with data obtained in children younger than 18 years. Twenty-five percent are less than 2 years old.

One of my candidate predictors requires that a child have sufficient verbal skills to report a particular symptom.

By design, all children less than 2 were considered 'Pre-verbal/Non-verbal'. Some older children were also felt to be 'Pre-verbal/Non-verbal', e.g. 64% of two-year-olds and 32% of three-year-olds.

Currently the candidate predictor variable is coded as a factor with 6 levels (no, mild, moderate, severe, unknown severity, pre-verbal/Non-verbal).

I created a second binary variable 'verbal' where 1=verbal and 0=nonverbal.

How should I best include this symptom as a predictor in my model?  It does not seem quite right to include the 'pre-verbal/Non-verbal' category in my symptom variable.

Comment: Is there a distinction between "unknown severity" and "non-verbal"? Does your method handle missing values?

Comment: Yes.  Some children were coded as having the symptom, but couldn't quantify severity, ie. "unknown severity".  Others were coded as unable to report the symptom, ie. "pre-verbal/Non-verbal".  These data contain some missing values as well.  I was planning to do multiple imputation of missing values.

Answer (score 1):

If you are proposing to include the candidate predictor as an unordered categorical variable there would seem to be no problem in having a category in it for pre-verbal.

If the predictor is ordered categorical or continuous then you can include it plus a binary indicator for pre-verbal in the model. Make sure they both go in together though. For a concrete and slightly silly illustration suppose you have two predictors, sex (women (=1) versus men (=0)) and hysterectomy (yes (-1) versus no (=0). When you include them both in the model together the coefficient for the first will tell you the (log) odds ratio for women compared to men and the second will tell you the extra effect of having had a hysterectomy if you are a woman.